# SQL Select Count Values negative positive and zero values

Tags: sql, select, count

```
Select * from Table

Date            Value
2013-06-24      12
2013-06-24      3
2013-06-24     -4
2013-06-24      33
2013-06-25      12
2013-06-25     -2
2013-06-25      43
2013-06-25      1
2013-06-25     -3
```

and now I will count all negative, positive and zero values group by Date in one SQL-Command.

Comment: Any effort? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. [But, look into the CASE expression.]

Comment: select count(case when Value < 0), count(case when Value > 0), count(case when Value = 0) from Table group by Date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
Date,
SUM(CASE WHEN Value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pos,
SUM(CASE WHEN Value < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS neg,
SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS zero
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 2):

You could;

```
select
    DATE,
    SUM(case when value < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NEGATIVE,
    SUM(case when value > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as POSITIVE,
    SUM(case when value = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ZERO
from 
    T
group by date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select date, count(case when value < 0 then value end) as Negative, 
count(case when value > 0 then value end) as positive
from the_table
```

Hope it helps!